# Facing issue using map function in perl

Tags: perl

I have the below lines:

```
7290741.out:Info: /test doesn't exist, Running on Network location
7300568.out:sh: /tmp/test/1234_123_test/test1/test2/abc.txt: bad interpreter
```

I have these lines in an array `@test1`.
I want to fetch only the numbers before `.out` and put them in an array `@test2`.

I used the below code for this:

```
foreach my $test1(@test1) {
    my @test2;
    map { /(d+)\.out/ and push @test2, $1 } <$error>;
    print "@test2\n";
}
```

But, when I execute the code, it is printing complete lines, and I want the output like below:

```
7290741
7300568
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: Neither of those errors come from the code you posted

Comment: I think the errors are part of their input text, not actual errors the program outputs.

Comment: The d+ needs to have a back slash in front of it.  should be:  /^(\d+)\.out/ but toolic answer is simpler and the way I would do it.

Comment: You say you have the lines in `@test1`. Then what are you reading from the filehandle `<$error>`? If you already read the lines, the filehandle would be empty.

Answer (score 4):

When I ran your code, I just got 2 blank lines of output.

Regardless, here is a simpler version of your code which just prints out the numbers:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my @test1;
while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    push @test1, $_;
}

my @test2;
for (@test1) {
    push @test2, $1 if /(\d+)\.out/;
}

for (@test2) {
    print "$_\n";
}

__DATA__
7290741.out:Info: /test doesn't exist, Running on Network location
7300568.out:sh: /tmp/test/1234_123_test/test1/test2/abc.txt: bad interpreter
```

There are numerous problems with your code.

You should use `warnings` and `strict`.

The `$error` variable was not defined in the code you posted.

`d` in the regular expression should have been `\d`.

You should have declared the `@test2` variable outside the `foreach` loop; otherwise, it would only have a single value due to variable scoping.

Answer (score 1):

```
my @nums = map { /^(\d+)\.out/ } <$errors>
```

Is the simplest way to put it, using map. When you try to first read the errors into an array (`@test1`) and loop around those values, and inside the loop try to read the values again, you are doing the same thing twice. `map` is also a loop.

This is assuming that your file with errors is what the filehandle `$errors` is reading from. Remember also to always use

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps OP is looking for solution of following form

Explanation:

- `<DATA>` in this context will represent an array of lines
- `map` will form a loop through lines
- *regex* extracts portion of information OP interested in
- result is stored in `@test` array

NOTE: Data::Dumper is used only for the result visualization

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
#
# vim: ai ts=4 sw=4

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Data::Dumper;

my @test = map { /^(.*?).out/ } <DATA>;

say Dumper(\@test);

__DATA__
7290741.out:Info: /test doesn't exist, Running on Network location
7300568.out:sh: /tmp/test/1234_123_test/test1/test2/abc.txt: bad interpreter
```

Output

```
$VAR1 = [
          '7290741',
          '7300568'
        ];
```